# UI AUTOMATION: How can an element exists but not be hittable?

Tags: objective-c, ios-ui-automation

Ok so i'm drawing a blank here.First condition is true, second it isn't when i run it. How can this be?

I'm using the latest xcode, latest os.

XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];

XCUIElement *usernameTextField = app.textFields[@"Username"];

```
if (usernameTextField.exists) {
    NSLog(@"condition returns true");
}else if ( usernameTextField.hittable){
    NSLog(@"doesn't execute");
}
```

[usernameTextField tap];
App then fails when i tap on it with:
UI Test Activity: 
Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - App failed to quiesce within 30.0s

Any ideas?

Comment: why is the second condition in an else statement if you want both to be true? If the first is true, second will not be executed for sure

Comment: If something exists, but is not hittable, maybe it's hidden or has a zero frame?

Answer (score 0):

Hittablility is an indicator of whether or not a gesture can be processed using a give point.

Given that UI tests flatten the view hierarchy to a query-based system, this just means that if part of a view is on screen it's hittable, otherwise it is not hittable.

For instance, if I have a `UITableView` that has a bunch of cells, the first cells that you can see on screen are hittable. The last cells that you can't see because they're off screen are not hittable.

An element can still exist in the coordinate space and be off screen. In the previous example, the last cell of a long table view would still exist, it just would be impossible to interact with it.